# Jenkins Performance plugin not listing URLs from JMeter test

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

In my JMeter setup, I have the following config in my ***Test Aggregate Report*** (named loadTestAggregate) in order to list all the erroring URLs in my load test :

[image]

When I run my JMeter test locally, this Test Aggregate Report correctly displays the results (as a .csv) and the URLs are displayed as required (i.e. the response code, response message and URL are all displayed).

I then set up this test to run via Jenkins (with the Performance plugin installed).

Below is the Jenkinsfile used to run this test via Jenkins;

```
sh "jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.url=true -n -t loadTest.jmx -JTest_Url=${env.TEST_URL} -l jmeter_results.jtl"
                    perfReport errorFailedThreshold: 5.00, sourceDataFiles:'loadTestAggregate.csv'
```

However, when the test is completed and I look in Jenkins via the Performance plugin, the URLs are not displayed.

All that's displayed is the following;

[image]

Is it possible to get these (erroring) URLs to be listed via the Jenkins Performance plugin?

If so, am I missing something here as my config for the Test Aggregate report works locally but not via Jenkins, so I can only presume that it's a Performance plugin issue.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're "aggregate" charts per [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) label

As a workaround you can change the Sampler label (`HTTP Request`) to the Sampler URL, it can be done via [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code:

```
prev.setSampleLabel(prev.getUrlAsString())
```

where `prev` stands for the **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Dmitri T this works perfectly. Many thanks for your help with this, you're a star!